# Invoke x86 dll from Azure Worker Role

Tags: opencv, azure, pinvoke, azure-worker-roles

I have created a Azure Worker Role Project. Target machine of the project has to be x64 machine. I should invoke Stasm and OpenCV dll from the worker role. But I think that they can be compiled on x86 machine.
What should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The worker role process is indeed x64. But it's just for that specific process. You could have an other process interact with those x86 dlls:

- Maybe you can write all your logic in a console application (x86) and include it in your worker role project. Then in the **Run** method of your WorkerRole.cs class, you can simply start that process (using Process.Start) to do the actual work and your WorkerRole.cs class would only be used as entry point.
- You could also simply host a WCF service in an external process (this could again be a simple console application compiled in x86). Then, using a binding like NetTcpBinding or NetNamedPipeBinding you could call that service from your worker role.

Answer (score 3):

Basically you are trying to use a native C++ DLL in your worker role so technically you want to access native modules in your worker role. I don't think OpenCV x86 binary is any issue with Worker ole instead being native, would require little extra efforts.

Totally agree with what @Sandrino suggest however would like to add thing in his #1) suggestion. When you have create your native EXE which includes all the logic to use OpenCV, it is best to launch is directly from ProgramEntryPoint settings in ServiceDefinition and you dont need to have any code added in Worker role, unless your have TCP/IP Endpoints and would want to use in your application. The Service Definition would be as below:

```
<WorkerRole name="Your_WorkerRole" vmsize="Small">
 <Runtime executionContext="limited">
  <EntryPoint>
    <ProgramEntryPoint commandLine="_your_application_.exe _Parameters_" setReadyOnProcessStart="true" />
  </EntryPoint>
 </Runtime>
 <Endpoints>
   <InputEndpoint name="_Your_Endpoint_" protocol="tcp" port="80" />
 </Endpoints>
```

I personally think second option above could be overkill comparative to #1.

Comment: +1 for mentioning ProgramEntryPoint, this is far more elegant

Comment: Useful reference article by the same author who wrote this answer - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2011/10/04/using-programentrypoint-element-in-service-definition-to-use-custom-application-as-role-entry-point-using-windows-azure-sdk-1-5.aspx